# Add tools and background sections to Careers PDF export

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, pdf

Your Careers 2.0 profile has two 'special interests' sections:

[image]

Unfortunately, these are not included in the PDF export, not even as an option. Could these be added?

Comment: yes i also want this feature to be added so my background details can be added in PDF. +1 to this question

Comment: I have found a workaround. I added my background details in my last project's description and it is coming in pdf. I added background as a title, so it can be read in pdf as new heading.

Answer (score 3):

I can get this behind us.  I'll add it this weekend.

EDIT:
This is done and on it's way out now.  Turns out there were **tons** of bugs on this page so I tried to clean up a good portion of them but I expect you'll find more with little effort.

Comment: "get this behind this"? What this this means?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: aw, don't scare him away?! I bet you spooked the dev looking at my feature-request now..

Comment: @MartijnPieters typo was nuked maybe now he'll come over. ;)

Comment: Another reason to not take on "small" projects: get started and find out a large portion of the resume creator is **not** localized correctly :/

Comment: Looks like it caused [couple](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240725/bugs-in-careers-pdf-generation) of [bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240556/cant-hide-tools-or-background-section-on-pdf-export?lq=1).