# How to add background details when I export my CV to PDF on Careers?

Tags: support, jobs

I am new to Careers 2.0 and I want my background details when I export my CV to PDF. How do I do that?

I found a workaround... but as this question is marked as duplicate I am not able to answer it.

I just copy pasted my background details in the description of my last open source project, and I made it as heading, So by just designing little bit it now appears in pdf as I wanted!!!

May be this will help someone until the feature is added by Stack overflow.

Comment: This is currently not possible and a request to add such feature already exists.

Comment: I have found a workaround. I added my background details in my last project's description and it is coming in pdf. I added background as a title, so it can be read in pdf as new heading.

Comment: Nice, can you add this as a new answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139705/add-tools-and-background-sections-to-careers-pdf-export) then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about Careers 2.0 are on-topic for [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). From the [MSE *What topics can I ask about here?* help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question is about:
>
> [...]
>
> - [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)
>
> [...]
>
> … it is welcome here.

Because the domain name uses `stackoverflow.com` it is usually fine to ask here to, but usually such posts are then migrated over to Meta Stack Exchange.

As for your background details, if you are asking about the *tools* and *backgrounds* sections, those are not currently included in the PDF. I've previously posted a feature-request to have those added:

[Add tools and background sections to Careers PDF export](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139705/add-tools-and-background-sections-to-careers-pdf-export)

Comment: Thanks.. +1 I hope this feature will be added soon. But why stack overflow is not adding this feature??