# Can't hide Tools or Background section on PDF Export

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, pdf

To reproduce the Bug, do the following:

1. On your Careers profile, click the Create PDF Link
2. On the show/hide section link, unselect all items under the Tools and Background menus
3. Click on Export to PDF.
4. The Tools and Background sections are included in the generated file.

Comment: Since both sections where [added to the PDF export together](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139705/add-tools-and-background-sections-to-careers-pdf-export), it makes sense that switching them off is broken for both at the same time too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this - I've now fixed this, so you can toggle the Tools and Background sections and it will actually respect that in the generated PDF.