# PDF Generation preview showing more pages than the actual document

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, pdf

The PDF generation in careers.se appears to have a bug.

- The preview shows my CV running into 3 pages, even though the generated PDF runs to two (or at least it WOULD be 2 if it didn't erroneously print the background section, as reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240556/cant-hide-tools-or-background-section-on-pdf-export)).

To repro any devs should be able to pull up my account and run the pdf generation.

Comment: The first bug is already reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240556/cant-hide-tools-or-background-section-on-pdf-export), can you please edit it out, leaving only the incorrect page count bug?

Comment: @shadow - done - thanks.

Comment: Cheers, although now that you mention the cause of the mismatch is the background section maybe it's a dupe after all since fixing it would also fix the count mismatch.

Comment: Also off topic comment, the first picture in your About Me section is broken, looks like it's just sending an empty response. (looks like they changed the URL to http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51tZ1lgpmyL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-v3-big,TopRight,0,-55_SX278_SY278_PIkin4,BottomRight,1,22_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

Comment: @Shadow - no, not a dupe.  The preview does NOT show the background, but still runs to 3 pages.  The PDF generation would only run to 2 pages if the background thing were fixed.  So the bug in pages is in the preview section.

Comment: Have you updated your resume? When I tried it, the preview shows 3 pages and the exported pdf had 3 pages. What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: @Juice - you can mark this as status completed.  In order to repro, you needed to hide background, technical skills, and projects and interests.  I just did, and the preview shows 2 pages, and it prints 3, but the third page is just the background (which prints even if hidden, for which you have another case linked in the first comment above)

Answer (score 1):

I can still reproduce this if I log in as you, but only in Chrome on OS X. Using Chrome on Windows, I can't reproduce the problem.

It's all down to differences in font rendering. If there is any difference in the font, that will change the size of words and therefore it will affect how many pages your PDF is split across. You're seeing the preview generated in your browser of course, but the PDF itself is generated on our servers, so there is always the potential for this to occur.

Our servers run on Windows, which explains why the generated PDF matches the number of pages I see in Chrome on Windows, and I only see a difference when using OS X.

It just so happens that the current content of your CV means it's borderline whether it will take up two pages or three!